# usercontrols inside panels

Tags: c#-2.0

In my project i added a usercontrol to a panel.when i try to add a new usercontrol to
my panel i want to check what is the name of the usercontrol placed in the panel before
how to do it.

i have three different usercontrols, i assign it one by one to panel,before replacing
the new one with the old one ,i want to find what is the old one inside the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the name like this:

```
Panel pnl= new Panel();
...

UserControl myControl = new UserControl();
myControl.Name = "muUserControl";
pnl.Controls.Add(myControl);



foreach (Control ctrl in pnlUserControlContainer.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is UserControl)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ctrl.Name);
                    }
                }
```